Are Transactions executed before they're forwarded?
To be more precise, I'm asking if transaction forwarding and execution takes place concurrently.
Imagine it this way:
Leader receives transaction XYZ and as soon as the transaction is scheduled, the leader ships it out to other nodes.
Since the other nodes will reach the same result as a honest leader, the leader can just continuously ship the batches of scheduled transactions before it executes them and ship just the results after. And then we can reach consensus on the execution results.
I imagine it's already being done this way but every explanation I find makes it sound like transactions are executed before they're forwarded and I just wanted to be clear.

Currently, transactions are in fact executed before they're sent out to the rest of the network.
The main reason for this design is to allow the leader to validate all fee payers in a block, so they can collect maximum rewards and avoid broadcasting transactions with invalid fee payers.
For example, I can sign and send 2 transactions to the leader with my keypair, where the first transaction drains my signing keypair of all SOL, which means that I won't be able to pay for the second transaction. This is a total waste of blockspace since the leader can't earn on my second transaction. And in fact, the rest of the network also needs to waste time on an invalid transaction. Now imagine that I constantly spam transactions with invalid fee payers -- that would be an effective DOS vector on the network!
I imagine that you realize the inefficiency with this approach. This is why there's a lot of design work around the concept of "bankless leaders" or "async execution" where block packing is completely separated from execution. It's definitely the future, but a bit far off. You can find more information about the idea at https://github.com/solana-foundation/solana-improvement-documents/pull/5

thanks!
You're not Jon Charb by any means are you :)
Thanks again!

haha nope, sorry! and you're very welcome

wait, then are you the core developer Jon?  If you are I've been reading a lot of your code, your comments on ticks and entries were super helpful. Would love to jam off Stack overflow if you're interested. you can find me on Twitter, Telegram and Discord @fikunmi_ap. Great stuff man and if you aren't thanks again for the answer!

Haha yep that's me! Feel free to drop in the Solana Discord if you ever have more core tech questions
